# TinyMCE custom dialog input size

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-plugins, tinymce-6

Is there any way to change the input elements size in a TinyMCE custom dialog? In the documentation I only see theese options:

```
{
  type: 'input', // component type
  name: 'inputA', // identifier
  inputMode: 'text',
  label: 'Input Label', // text for the label
  placeholder: 'example', // placeholder text for the input
  enabled: false, // disabled state
  maximized: false // grow width to take as much space as possible
}
```